# Convergence of series containing sin

Tags: sequences-and-series

If we know that a series a(n) converge, then do the series  a(n). sin(n)  also converge?

I tried some series and proved that if a(n) converges absolutely then the series  a(n). sin(n) also converge.

But is it true in case of any convergent series?

Comment: Do you mean series or sequence?

Comment: @lulu I mean series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $a(n) = \sin(n)/n$.  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi - 1}{2}$.

Comment: I don't get it. What is $\pi - 1 in the end doing?

Comment: This is proof that this choice of $a(n)$ yields a converging series.  Now use this $a(n)$ in your proposed process.

Comment: thanks a lot XD